# JS how to use variable value instead of variable point itself

Tags: javascript

Here is my easy code. I want to the two function get different result, but the global variable precision passed is the pointer. So it get same result for two function.

```js
precision = 4
func = (value) => value.toFixed(precision)
precision = 2
func2 = (value) => value.toFixed(precision)
console.log(func(2.3333))
console.log(func2(2.3333))
```

Can anyone tell me how to use the value of precision instead of itself? Then the two function should return different result.

Comment: This is not how JS works. The value of `precision` is read when the function is executed, not when the function is defined. If you want that, you can add a second argument, or you can create a scope by returning a higher order function (though, please don't, that seems really complicated for no reason). Also, use `const` and `let` to make your code more accessible and clearer, but that's neither here not there.

Comment: In practice, why wouldn't you simply be writing `func = (value) => value.toFixed(4)`? Please ensure you're not simplifying your examples to the point where they make little sense.

Comment: Thanks for comments, Because this function is restricted to have only one parameter value And the precision is get from outside, we never know it is 4 or other int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over `precision` and get a function for the value.

```js
const
    fix = precision => value => value.toFixed(precision),
    fix4 = fix(4),
    fix2 = fix(2);

console.log(fix2(2.3333));
console.log(fix4(2.3333));
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a different value for `precision` for each function call, pass the precision as function argument. This will eliminate the need for a second function:

```js
const fixedNumber = (value, precision) => value.toFixed(precision);

console.log(fixedNumber(2.333, 2));
console.log(fixedNumber(2.333, 3));
```

As can be seen from the output of your example, set function will read the value when it is called and not when it was defined.